# Is there an easy way to access the Display name (title) of each command listed in the Keyboard Shortcuts JSON file?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I'm trying to write a script which converts the user's keyboard shortcuts into flashcards. I want to essentially make a list of (shortcut, action title) for each shortcut.

When I open the default shortcut JSON, I see (key, command, when) for each shortcut. For example:

`{ "key": "escape escape", "command": "workbench.action.exitZenMode", "when": "inZenMode" },`

This is perfect, except that I want the command to be human-readable. When I open the "Keyboard Shortcut" editor, shortcuts are listed by English name, for example:

"Add Cursor Above" - "`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `UpArrow`" - "`editorTextFocus`"

This is what I want, but I can't export these.

I dug through the repo on GitHub. It looks like the commands are each defined in their own file, and each one has a property called `title` that contains the English name, but I couldn't figure out how the Keyboard Shortcut editor accesses each of these commands and displays their title (I'm not a typescript pro). What's the best way to get a list of keyboard command English names?

Comment: I don't really see what this has to do with TypeScript. Could you elaborate or retag this question?

Comment: The repo is written in typescript, so I thought maybe there's a well-known or easy way to access objects by ID and get their titles. Here's an example of one of the objects in the codebase, I want to find all of these and get the `alias` or `title` property. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/a6b9e7c28b08a7da5aa7deb760a0bfddbc18bec3/src/vs/editor/contrib/multicursor/browser/multicursor.ts#L98

Comment: Right. So is this question as simple as, "how to access things in objects?" TypeScript doesn't have any effect on runtime code either.

Comment: I guess; there are really two things I need to do. Get the object from the ID and get the property (title or alias) from the object. I know how to do the second one but not the first. Again I'm not a typescript programmer.

Comment: Okay, what I'm saying is that this doesn't have anything to do with TypeScript. It doesn't matter if you don't know TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm pretty sure you don't actually want the contents of the default keybindings JSON pseudo file. I assume that if you want flashcards, you want to help someone remember *their* keybindings, along with any customizations they've made to them.

I dunno about easy **or** scriptable, but... here goes (the best I can think of right now):

0. Enable and activate all extensions that contribute keybindings that you want to be part of the result. Extensions have activation events (so they don't get loaded unless they are actually needed).
1. Open the VS Code devtools (`Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette))
2. Open the "Sources" tab and go open "Electron Isolated Context" > ".../resources/app" (or whatever the path to app resources is for your VS Code installation) > out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js.
3. <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and search for `getKeybindings() {` and put a breakpoint on the results. Ex. for me, I got two search results, and put the breakpoint here (you may see something slightly different because this is minified code):

   ```js
   getKeybindings() {
       return this.e // <- put breakpoint here
   }
   ```

   The breakpoint will be rendered in a prettified / source-mapped(?) view of the code.
4. Go back to the actual VS Code window, and now open the keyboard shortcuts UI (`Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts` in the command palette). This should trigger the breakpoint.
5. In the devtools' "Sources" tab, press the "Step out of current function" button twice, which should take you into a function called `resolve` in `keybindingsEditorModel.ts`.
6. Right click the line that declares `const commandsWithDefaultKeybindings` and click "Continue to here". Note that if you actually want to get default keybindings instead of user keybindings + non-overridden default keybindings, then the for loop that follows this is the one that initializes the data you want.
7. In the right sidebar, under the "Scope" section, under its "Local" section, look for a property of `this` that is an array with (probably lots of) stuff in it. The property names will be minified. In the original source code, the name of what we're looking for is `_keybindingItemsSortedByPrecedence`. Once you find it, right click it and select "Store object as global variable". You'll see a new variable in the console panel, probably named something like `temp1`.
8. In the console, run `temp1.map(e => ({command:e.commandLabel,keyChord:e.keybindingItem.chords})).filter(e=>e.command!=="")` (or whatever transformation you want to get the properties you want and in whatever format you want) The filter removes mappings that just have `""` as their label. I think those mappings are just for keys that aren't bound to a command and just "insert" themselves / do the normal thing they would do in any application.
9. right click the result and select "Copy object".
10. Click "continue" in the debugger
11. Paste the clipboard contents wherever you want and do whatever you want with the result (it's JSON).

This would probably be a lot easier if there was / I could find an extension API to get keybindings, but I looked and didn't find one. (Maybe I just missed it?)

If you want to filter by the source (what registers the keybinding), then you can do that too. Ex. to filter for keybindings written by the user: `temp1.filter(e=>e.source==="User") ...`. To get a list of sources, use `new Set(temp1.map(e=>e.source))`. Note that some of the sources are objects instead of strings (Ex. objects about extension sources as opposed to `"System"` or `"User"`).

---

If you have any interest in extension API access, see [API: Expose list of keybindings #162433](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162433). It's closed for not receiving enough community support in time, but you can try it again and try to get enough support for it.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.