How do I know a command to add a shortcut in VSCode
I repeatitly use this click in vs code source control.

When you just press ENTER you get the comparison view. I would like to add a shortcut for opening the actual file. But how do I know which command this one triggers in order to add a shortcut for it?
Is there maybe an extension that shows the command when you click something?
Many thanks

This question is similar to: Open file instead of open changes by default in source control window. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (git.openFile)

@brc-dd it is not a duplicate of the post you are suggesting, as mine was a generic question using this as an example.

@starball Thanks for the hint, that was exactly what I was looking for :)

can you please adapt the duplication information, as currently it shows the wrong post ...

as I already told you, I can't close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77919622/11107541 because it has no upvoted answer. if you want it to be usable as a duplicate target, and if my answer there helps you, you can upvote it.

sorry, I completely missed that. I did upvote the answer now
